# Datajacks and rigger control rigs

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

The description of a rigger control rig includes a throw away comment that 'it's like getting a free datajack' (5th ed. Core Rulebook p.265).

Am I supposed to take this literally and assume that if I have a control rig, I do not also need a datajack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a datajack is cyberware that *only* provides a DNI (direct neural interface).

The Rigger Control Rig (as well as the implanted commlink or implanted cyberdeck) also provides a DNI, so it provides all the features of a datajack.

The sentence immediately before the one you quoted is this:

> It [..] comes with a universal data connector and about a meter of retractable cable.

Which is pretty much exactly what a datajack is (plus it mentions storage, but raw storage has been abstracted away in SR5).